# Sending messages in android-midi-lib

Tags: android, midi

I'm using android-midi-lib https://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/ to generate music. I'm trying to switch instrument, but all channels sound the same (piano), as it should be. After digging around I found out that I should send `ProgramChange` message to channels so they use different intruments, but I have no idea how I should do this. So, how do I send message to channel or any messages at all?
Here's the code I'm using

```
    // 2. Add events to the tracks
    // Track 0 is the tempo map
    TimeSignature ts = new TimeSignature();
    ts.setTimeSignature(4, 4, TimeSignature.DEFAULT_METER, TimeSignature.DEFAULT_DIVISION);

    Tempo tempo = new Tempo();
    tempo.setBpm(128);

    tempoTrack.insertEvent(ts);
    tempoTrack.insertEvent(tempo);

    // Track 1 will have some notes in it
    final int NOTE_COUNT = 80;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int beat1 = rand.nextInt((81 - 35) + 1) + 35;
    int beat2 = rand.nextInt((81 - 35) + 1) + 35;
    int beat3 = rand.nextInt((81 - 35) + 1) + 35;
    for(int i = 0; i < NOTE_COUNT; i++)

    {
        int pitch = rand.nextInt((80 - 30) + 1) + 30;
        int channel = alkuChannel;
        //int channelTest = 1;
        //int pitch = alkuPitch + i;
        int velocity = 100;
        long tick = i * alkuTick;
        long duration = 120;
        noteTrack.insertNote(channel, pitch, velocity, tick, duration);
        noteTestTrack.insertNote(9, beat1, 100, tick, duration*2);
        if (i%2==0) {
            noteTestTrack.insertNote(9, beat2, 100, tick, duration*2);
        }
    }

    // 3. Create a MidiFile with the tracks we created
    ArrayList<MidiTrack> tracks = new ArrayList<MidiTrack>();
    tracks.add(tempoTrack);
    tracks.add(noteTrack);
    tracks.add(noteTestTrack);

    MidiFile midi = new MidiFile(MidiFile.DEFAULT_RESOLUTION, tracks);
```

Comment: How do you send your other messages?

Comment: Oh, badly shaped question, should be better now. So I don't know hiw to send any messages

Comment: How do you get piano sounds without note-on messages?

Comment: So I'm using the example code provided, it's now in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [implementation of `insertNote()`](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib/blob/master/src/com/leff/midi/MidiTrack.java#L163):

```js
public void insertNote(int channel, int pitch, int velocity, long tick, long duration)
{
    insertEvent(new NoteOn(tick, channel, pitch, velocity));
    insertEvent(new NoteOn(tick + duration, channel, pitch, 0));
}
```

Just do the same with a `ProgramChange` event:

```js
track.insertEvent(new ProgramChange(tick, channel, program));
```